# Can someone tell me what is wrong with this python code?

Tags: python

Can someone tell me what is wrong with this python code? I am a newbie and have been trying to run this:

```py
legs = input('Number of legs he have?\n')
def Dance(legs):
    if legs = 'Two':
        print('HE HAVE TWO LEGS SO HE CAN  DANCE')
    elif legs:
        print('HE HAVE ONE LEG AND HE CAN DO SOMETHING')
    else:
        print('NO LEGS SO HE CANT DANCE')
```

Comment: Dance is a function in order to pass in the variable that is created from the input() that you used you should do `Dance(legs)` after the function

Comment: `=` is assignment, use `==` to compare.

Answer (score 0):

the function needs to be called. try this:

```
legs = int(input('Number of legs he have?\n'))
def Dance(legs):
    if legs == 2:
        print('HE HAVE TWO LEGS SO HE CAN  DANCE')
    elif legs == 1:
        print('HE HAVE ONE LEG AND HE CAN DO SOMETHING')
    else:
        print('NO LEGS SO HE CANT DANCE')

Dance(legs) # this invokes/calls the function
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to have the input statement inside the function, which makes it cleaner:

```
def Dance():
    legs = input('Number of legs he has?\n')
    if legs == 'Two':
        print('HE HAS TWO LEGS SO HE CAN  DANCE')
    elif legs == 'One':
        print('HE HAS ONE LEG AND HE CAN DO SOMETHING')
    elif legs == 'Zero':
        print('NO LEGS SO HE CANNOT DANCE')
    else:
        print('I do not understand your input')

Dance()   #this invokes/calls the function
```

Output:

```
Number of legs he has?
 One
HE HAS ONE LEG AND HE CAN DO SOMETHING
```